# Firewall Redirect Event

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I try to intercept when the firewall in symfony2 decides to redirect to the login.

My goal is to track the url that was supposed to be called and keep it (*session or even cookie*) for whenever a successfull login happens (*So even if the user registers and follows double-opt-in first*). So i need the currently called url (*not just path*) and the request (*in order to write to session/cookie*).

I tried browsing thru the symfony2 code but can't find anything. It didn't say anything about that in the documentation either.

Anyone any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution wherei listen on `kernel.exception`.
When an Exception is thrown i check if it is an instance of `AccessDeniedException` and react on it.

This is my service Definition:

```
whatever_bundle.event_listener.exception_listener:
    class: WhateverBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, priority: 1 }
```

And this is the Listener Class:

```
<?php
namespace WhateverBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->getException() instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            doTheThingsYouWantToDoInThisCase();
        }
    }
}
```